# How to use looping to create and return 5 rows dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, url, load

I was requested to create a JSON dataframe using looping only, with specific headers: headers = {'User-agent': 'CS6400'} in request.get(). In addition, dataframe with 5 rows (one for each of the top 25 posts).
Since I only can use looping, not able to use "read_json" or "json_normalize". I was stuck for several hours, support needed and much appreciated.
Here is my buggy codes:(error message :ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 122 )

```
import urllib, json
import requests
import  gzip
import json
url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/popular/top.json"
headers = {'User-agent': 'DS6001'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
data = json.dumps(response)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")  
dataframe
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can also share the error message here.

Comment: The error message is like this :
ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 122